# Basic script fails to run on other computers, missing libstdc++-6.dll

Tags: c++, libraries

I have a brand new computer, I install VScode along with recommended packages for C++ (recommended by VSC) and write a C++ "Hello World" script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>


int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World";
  sleep(5);
}
```

This script does not run on other machines with C++ installed, it returns an error saying libstdc++-6.dll is missing and the script cannot run.

I did not perform any custom installations, I have simply followed the VScode [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) on installing C++. I complied it into an .exe using g++.

What have I done that means a rudimentary, compiled `hello_world.exe` will only run on my machine? I don't see how I could be using a specialised library.

Comment: ```libstdc++6``` is GCC's C++ standard library. Try copying it over from your system (probably from your MSYS2 installation) and put it right next to your EXE file.

Comment: From both these answers, in theory, if it runs on my computer (without the libraries having been moved and duplicated) but not on other computers, does this mean the other machines haven't had Mingw-w64 in stalled correctly?

Comment: @SolebaySharp Both compilers need to have the DLL (either manually copied or from a MinGW installation) in the correct path (for example in the same directory as the executable, see linked duplicate). Furthermore, with some exceptions, they must be the same versions. That means generally you can't have two different MinGW versions/distributions on the two machines and use the DLL from one with a program compiled with the other.